# Put class on class

Tags: python, python-3.x

how would I go about doing the pseudo code below

```py
import bClass
import cClass

class aClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = aClass()
a.bClass = bClass()
a.cClass = cClass()
```

How would I put these classes on this parent class?
When I try I get

```
p.GlobalHistory = GlobalHistory()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Thanks,

Comment: These are not classes, these are modules. I'm confused

Comment: Me too, how would I export a class specifically from a file?

Comment: use `from <file name> import <class name>` :)

Comment: from file import class

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've defined `class bClass` in `bClass.py`, and `class cClass` in `cClass.py`. What you've imported are the modules, not the classes themselves. The classes are then `bClass.bClass`, i.e., name `bClass` inside module `bClass`.

You can access the class like this:

```
a.bClass = bClass.bClass()
```

or change your import like this:

```
from bClass import bClass
a.bClass = bClass()
```